# I have installed android studio and then deleted it.\ how should I stop that running android studio?

Tags: windows-7

I have installed android studio and then deleted it.While re installing androidstudio it is showing androidstudio is already running?
 how should I stop that running android studio?

Answer (score 0):

Check the Task Manager if Android Studio is still running in background.

Hit Ctrl + Shift + Escape and on the Processes tab find Android Studio and End Process.